# How do I configure Serde to use an enum variant's discriminant rather than name?

Tags: enums, rust, serde

I'm parsing an INI-style file that uses integers for enumerators.

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub enum MyThing {
    First = 0,
    Second = 1,
    Third = 2,
}
```

In the file, the value will get serialized like so:

```
thing=0
```

However, Serde by default matches against the variant name rather than the discriminant. Is custom-implementing `Deserialize` the cleanest method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Serde website has an [entire example on how to serialize an enum as a number](https://serde.rs/enum-number.html):

> ```
> [dependencies]
> serde = "1.0"
> serde_repr = "0.1"
> ```
>
> ```rust
> use serde_repr::*;
>
> #[derive(Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr, PartialEq, Debug)]
> #[repr(u8)]
> enum SmallPrime {
>     Two = 2,
>     Three = 3,
>     Five = 5,
>     Seven = 7,
> }
>
> fn main() {
>     use SmallPrime::*;
>     let nums = vec![Two, Three, Five, Seven];
>
>     // Prints [2,3,5,7]
>     println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&nums).unwrap());
>
>     assert_eq!(Two, serde_json::from_str("2").unwrap());
> }
> ```

I would believe that this is the best way to do it as it's recommended by the crate authors themselves.