# Can I serialize an enum's definition with serde?

Tags: rust, serde

Given this enum definition:

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
pub enum AnimalType {
    #[serde(rename = "cat")]
    Cat = 1,
    #[serde(rename = "dog")]
    Dog = 2,
    #[serde(rename = "snake")]
    Snake = 3,
    #[serde(rename = "capybara")]
    Capybara = 4,
}
```

I'd like to be able to return JSON defining the above enum similar to this:

```json
{
  "AnimalType": [
    { "cat": 1 },
    { "dog": 2 },
    { "snake": 3 },
    { "capybara": 4 }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to do this programmatically in Rust, possibly with `serde`?

This question differs from [How do I configure Serde to use an enum variant's discriminant rather than name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49604190/155423) as I want to serialize the **definition** of the enum, not a **value**.

Comment: I'll play clippy: It looks like you are trying to generate a schema for your types. Would you like help? Get help with [schemars](https://docs.rs/schemars/0.8.8/schemars/).

Comment: What is currently going wrong with your attempt to serialize (the definition)?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using `strum` and its `EnumVariantNames` macro: https://docs.rs/strum_macros/latest/strum_macros/derive.EnumVariantNames.html

```rust
#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Serialize, EnumVariantNames)]
pub enum AnimalType {
    #[serde(rename = "cat")]
    #[strum(serialize = "cat")]
    Cat = 1,
    #[serde(rename = "dog")]
    #[strum(serialize = "dog")]
    Dog = 2,
    #[serde(rename = "SNAKE")]
    #[strum(serialize = "SNAKE")]
    Snake = 3,
    #[serde(rename = "capybara")]
    #[strum(serialize = "capybara")]
    Capybara = 4,
}

async fn get_animal_types() -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
    Ok(warp::reply::json(&AnimalType::VARIANTS))
}
```

Returning `["cat","dog","SNAKE","capybara"]`

Comment: Do you need both the `serde(rename...)` and the `strum(serialize...)`, or is one of them the "important" one?