# How to Serialize Enum in Rust with Bincode While Retaining Enum Discriminant Instead of Index?

Tags: rust, enums, serde, bincode

I've been working on serializing an enum in Rust using bincode, but I am facing an issue where I receive the index of the enum variant instead of its assigned discriminant. Here's an example of the enum I'm trying to serialize:

```rust
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    #[repr(u64)]
    pub enum StreamOutputFormat {
        A(X) = 0x01,
        B(Y) = 0x02,
        C(Z) = 0x03,
    }
```

In this code, X, Y, and Z represent structs.

When I try to serialize an instance of `StreamOutputFormat::C(Z {some_z_stuff...})` using bincode like so:

```rust
let sof = StreamOutputFormat::C(Z {some_z_stuff...});
println!("sof: {:?}", bincode::serialize(&sof));
```

The output I get is:

```
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]
```

This is problematic because I need the serialized output to be the discriminant of the enum variant (in this case 0x03), not the index, due to interoperability requirements with other components. For comparison, other enums in my codebase that are unit enums serialize correctly using `(De)Serialize_repr`.

What is the correct way to serialize (and deserialize) this type of enum in bincode so that I receive the enum variant discriminant instead of its index?

Comment: Bincode does not have a specified format anyway, so you cannot rely on it.

Comment: They do seem to have a spec here: https://github.com/bincode-org/bincode/blob/trunk/docs/spec.md

Comment: Not sure if this works when the variants have data, but you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49604190/6274355

Comment: Given that `bincode` relies [entirely](https://docs.rs/bincode/1.3.3/src/bincode/ser/mod.rs.html#209) on the variant index when serializing, I don't think that `serde_repr` will work here. (I don't think it works with anything other than unit variants in the first place.)

Comment: My general approach would be this: [into](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#into)/[from](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from) your enum into a type where `#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]` produces whatever bincode you want. I see two possible types: `enum StreamOutputFormatSerde { _DummyVariant0, A(X), … }`, or `struct DicStreamOutputFormat (u64, StreamOutputFormatVar); #[serde(untagged)] enum StreamOutputFormatVar { A(X), … }`. ([Example for `from`/`try_into`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72484362/401059).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes this complicated is that serde's enum deserialization only allows strings, bytes, or `u32` for the enum tag (each format chooses one of those three). This is hardcoded into each format, for example [here in bincode](https://docs.rs/bincode/latest/src/bincode/de/mod.rs.html#284). An enum with a `u64` tag is essentially not an enum as far as serde is concerned.

So with that in mind, you have to serialize and deserialize your enum as something other than an enum. I've chosen to use a tuple, which is probably as close to an enum as you'll get. The serialization is quite simple since we know what type everything is.

```rs
impl Serialize for StreamOutputFormat {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        match self {
            StreamOutputFormat::A(x) => {
                let mut tuple = serializer.serialize_tuple(2)?;
                tuple.serialize_element(&0x01u64)?;
                tuple.serialize_element(x)?;
                tuple.end()
            }
            StreamOutputFormat::B(y) => {
                let mut tuple = serializer.serialize_tuple(2)?;
                tuple.serialize_element(&0x02u64)?;
                tuple.serialize_element(y)?;
                tuple.end()
            }
            StreamOutputFormat::C(z) => {
                let mut tuple = serializer.serialize_tuple(2)?;
                tuple.serialize_element(&0x03u64)?;
                tuple.serialize_element(z)?;
                tuple.end()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've kept this extremely repetitive for clarity. If you have a variant with more than one field, you will need to increment the number passed to `serialize_tuple`. Also don't forget the discriminants need to be `u64`.

Now the deserialization.

```rs
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for StreamOutputFormat {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        use serde::de::Error;

        struct StreamOutputFormatVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for StreamOutputFormatVisitor {
            type Value = StreamOutputFormat;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
                write!(
                    formatter,
                    "a tuple of size 2 consisting of a u64 discriminant and a value"
                )
            }

            fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: serde::de::SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                let discriminant: u64 = seq
                    .next_element()?
                    .ok_or_else(|| A::Error::invalid_length(0, &self))?;
                match discriminant {
                    0x01 => {
                        let x = seq
                            .next_element()?
                            .ok_or_else(|| A::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?;
                        Ok(StreamOutputFormat::A(x))
                    }
                    0x02 => {
                        let y = seq
                            .next_element()?
                            .ok_or_else(|| A::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?;
                        Ok(StreamOutputFormat::B(y))
                    }
                    0x03 => {
                        let z = seq
                            .next_element()?
                            .ok_or_else(|| A::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?;
                        Ok(StreamOutputFormat::C(z))
                    }
                    d => Err(A::Error::invalid_value(
                        serde::de::Unexpected::Unsigned(d),
                        &"0x01, 0x02, or 0x03",
                    )),
                }
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_tuple(2, StreamOutputFormatVisitor)
    }
}
```

Getting past the boilerplate, we have a call to `deserialize_tuple`, which will call `visit_seq` on the visitor. Inside that method, the visitor consumes a `u64` to use as the discriminant, and then consumes the inner data based on that discriminant.

## Methods that don't work

You can't serialize it by adding dummy fields to the enum since this would still use `u32` tags. Another thing you might try is deserializing through a `(u64, UntaggedEnum)` where `UntaggedEnum` is:

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
UntaggedEnum {
    A(X),
    B(Y),
    C(Z),
}
```

This doesn't work because non-self-describing formats can't handle untagged enums. On top of that, even self-describing formats could fail if the data is valid for more than one variant, since there is no simple way to conditionally deserialize the second element of a tuple depending on the first element. It is also inefficient since it will try to deserialize the enum even if the `u64` was invalid.

## Notes

You may have added `#[repr(u64)]` without knowing that serde enums need to be `u32`, and you can actually work with `#[repr(u32)]` enums as well. If that's the case, it appears that you can use serde's enum deserialization and it will be slightly simpler (very similar to what the `Deserialize` macro generates). As far as I could tell, you would need to map the discriminants to their respective variants.

Notably, the code I wrote never references the actual discriminants given in the enum definition. This is pretty standard for rust, since enum discriminants have very little functionality. You need to do [a pointer cast](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html#pointer-casting) to even read them, and they have absolutely no use in conditionally deserializing `X`, `Y`, and `Z`. If you remove them, it will have no effect on serialization.

If you intend to modify this enum, or if it has a large quantity of variants, then it would be a good use of time to turn this into a macro. This would not be too hard as a declarative macro since all the values you need are literals like `0x01` and the repetition is obvious.

I haven't checked out bincode 2.0, which includes its own `Decode` trait that doesn't use serde. It might be possible to decode `u64` enum tags, but the structure is completely different from serde, so I didn't look too much into it.

This may not match the format you want. Judging by the `u64` repr, whatever you're trying to deserialize wasn't made by a serde enum, so it's impossible for me to know if your format will match the tuple format I've used.

Comment: Thank you for the long and thought out response. Much appreciated.